# How to check Data Frame columns contains numeric values or not? Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with two columns - REGIONID & REGIONNAME

I want to update REGIONID with REGIONNAME if REGIONID contains Numeric values.

```
Data_All.loc[Data_All['REGIONID'].str.isnumeric() is True , 'REGIONID'] = Data_All['REGIONNAME']
```

I am getting error like

```
"KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `is True` because [`isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) return boolean mask:

```
Data_All.loc[Data_All['REGIONID'].str.isnumeric(), 'REGIONID'] = Data_All['REGIONNAME']
```

If necessary check `True`s (e. g. `NaN`s in column `REGIONID`):

```
Data_All.loc[Data_All['REGIONID'].str.isnumeric() == True, 'REGIONID'] = Data_All['REGIONNAME']
```